# split not working as required?

Tags: split

I want to split a file into 'n' chunks, the suffixes should be of 'a' length and should using numeric suffixes starting from number 'd'.

e.g. n = 10, a=4, d=5, As all options look correct and I tried the below

```
split -n10 -a4 -d5 somefile
split: cannot split in more than one way
Try 'split --help' for more information.
```

It gives the above error. The options look fine to me as per the man page

```
-a, --suffix-length=N
          generate suffixes of length N (default 2)

-d, --numeric-suffixes[=FROM]
          use numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic; FROM changes the start value (default 0)

-n, --number=CHUNKS
          generate CHUNKS output files; see explanation below
```

What could be the reason for the error? How can I achieve the stated goal?

Comment: You appear to be confounding the letter options `d` and `b`

Comment: My conclusion exactly. You cannot split into 10 files (`n=10`) and have each one only 5 bytes long (`b=5`).

Comment: @steeldrive Thanks fixed now.. it was a typo :)

Comment: @roaima fixed now.. it was a typo :)

Comment: @don_crissti can reproduce this behaviour ( `split (GNU coreutils) 8.23` on debian 8 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this command fails (even the one with the fixed typo) is that it is syntactically wrong.

> ```
> split -n10 -a4 -d5 somefile
> ```

The `-d` flag does not take a numeric argument. (Contrast this with the long version `--numeric-suffixes` which can.) See the [split invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#split-invocation) for the details that are unfortunately omitted from the derived man page.

Use this instead

```
split -n10 -a4 --numeric-suffixes=5 somefile
```

Comment: Thanks, but by the time i already file a bug on the mailing list. :)

Comment: Yes short options can't take an optional arg for back wards compat and operational reasons. Note also since coreutils v8.24 the man page links directly to the online info page, which the canonical source is now the simpler URL http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/split